# Проблема с циклом вектора строк с++

Tags: c++, строки, циклы, вектор

Есть код, читающий файл и выписывающий из него все объявленные переменные вместе с типами.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector <string> v(0);
    v.push_back("int");
    v.push_back("char");
    v.push_back("string");
    v.push_back("mas");
    v.push_back("bool");
    string b;
    string k;
    ifstream file("Studying.cpp");

    while (getline(file, b))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++)
            {
                if ((b.find(v[j]) != string::npos) && (b.find(";") != string::npos))
                {
                    int t = b.find(v[j]);
                    int h = b.find(";");
                    k = b.substr(t, h);
                    cout << k << endl;
                    b.erase(t, h + 1);
                }
                else b.erase();
            }
        }
    }

    file.close();
    system("pause");
```

Проблема заключается во втором цикле for. Он проверяет только первый элемент вектора, то есть v[0], а остальные опускает. Если же v[j] заменить на v[0]..v[4], то отлично выводит каждый из типов. Как сделать, чтобы выводил все, если такой цикл не работает?

Comment: Что вы хотите делать этими циклами. Какой должен быть результат? Что содержит переменная b после вызова getline?

Comment: Интересно, а зачем у вас цикл по `i`? Просто много раз делать одно и то же? :) `i` в теле цикла не используется...

Comment: b содержит одну прочитанную строку из файла и ищет в ней объявленные переменные(топорным способом конечно). если не нашел в ней один из типов и символ ';', то опускает строку и проверяет следующую, перезаписав ее вновь в переменную b.
Результат в консоли примерно такой:
int a;
int b;
string sdk;
bool fwjf;

Comment: Вы правы, можно опустить его) но к решению проблемы это все равно не приводит

Comment: @Greto  Вопрос следует закрыть, так как совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите достичь в программе, и как представлены входные данные в файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо массы прочей ерунды, смотрите - вот вы не нашли `int`. Что происходит? Условие `if` не выполняется, вы переходите к `else` и удаляете всю строку. И что вы хотите после этого в ней искать?...

И - ну прямо больно смотреть на лишние поиски - вынесите вы поиски перед `if`:

```
    int t = b.find(v[j]);
    int h = b.find(";");
    if ((t != string::npos) && (h != string::npos))
```

Но в любом случае без нормального синтаксического анализа вы будете получать много ерунды. Не все, что начинается с имени типа, и заканчивается `;` - объявление переменных...

Comment: Благодарю, заработало.
У меня задание не такое требовательное, поэтому хватит и подобного объявления переменных.

Comment: Ну, рад, что смог помочь. Если мой ответ вас удовлетворил - ставьте птицу :)